# How to name a route on a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, helper

If I have a controller `Home` with a single action `index`, I know I can write:

```
get 'home' => 'home#index"
```

and I will automatically have the named route `home_path`.

But if I define it like so:

```
resources :home, only: :index
```

I get the route `home_index_path`. Why is that and how can I create the named route `home_path`, if I use the `resources` convention.

Comment: you do have named route when you define route as `resources :home, only: :index`, you can call `home_path`.

Comment: Currently, if I use `home_path` in the application layout, I get `undefined local variable or method \`home_path'`, but `home_index_path` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails defines a standard naming convention for all resources in the routes file. See the [Rails Guide on Resource Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

You can also run `bundle exec rake routes` to see the names for the routes you've defined in your application.

In the case of your example, `resources :home, only: :index`, the named route for the `"homes#index"` action would be `homes_path` or `homes_url`.

**UPDATE**:

You may prefer `resource :home, only: :show` which would have a named route of `home_path` or `home_url`. Also the path to access the home resource (singular) would be `/home` whereas the the home resources (plural) index would be `/homes`.

Comment: But what if my controller is singular - HomeController? Currently, if I use `home_path` in my application layout I get `undefined local variable or method \`home_path'` and must use `home_index_path`.

Comment: The rails convention is that controller names are always plural regardless of how you access them. So `HomesController`.

Comment: Is this mandatory? I found this in the RailsGuides: `The naming convention of controllers in Rails favors pluralization of the last word in the controller's name, although it is not strictly required (e.g. ApplicationController).`

Comment: It's not mandatory but it allows you to use the defaults for routing if you follow the convention.

Comment: O.K., but there is one more funny thing: if I write `get '/home' => 'home#index'`, I automatically get `home_path`. Why is that?

Comment: It's hard to find anything in the documentation on why you get a named route of `home_path` out of `get '/home' => 'home#index'`... but I think it's just because Rails parses the string passed to `get` (`/home` in this case), strips off the leading `/` and provides a name based on the string `"home"`. It's just trying to help :).

Comment: OK, 10x for the help. I'll leave the question without a best answer to see if someone else has a solution and if not I'll select your answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use singular name controller with rails routing. try use :

```
resource :home, :controller => 'home'
```

Comment: This also creates `home_index_path` and not `home_path`.

Comment: please cross check your route it should be `resource` not `resources` like this `resource :home, :controller => 'home'`

Comment: You are completely right, I had written `resources :home`. So your solution works, however, it seems that if I add the `controller` parameter, I cannot use the `only` parameter anymore. If I write: `resource :home, controller: 'home'`, I also get the `new_home_path`, `edit_home_path` etc.. However, if I write `resource :home, controller: 'home', only: [:index]`, I don't get `home_path` anymore.

Comment: Yes you are right. I haven't checked it. Have a look at here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource you might get your desired solution.

Comment: Don't know why but it's not working for `index` method only. I have tried it on create and it works as expected `resource :home, path: "home", only: :create`. I have used path instead of controller.

Comment: I think the idea is that a `resource` is only a single object, part of a collection. A single object cannot be indexed and thus the index action is turned off.

Comment: Yes that may be the case. Thanks @AlexPopov ! But will go through it again when I get chance.