# How to satisfy both Rails controller naming conventions and naming of callback path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, callback, naming

When using an oauth provider I want to have a callback link like so: `base_url/callback`. I want to have a controller responding with its `index` action to this url. Here's the thing however - if I create a Callback**s**Controller the path to the index action will be:

```
base_url/callbacks
```

and I don't want it to be plural.

I don't want to use the `show` action as the oauth provider won't be providing a callback id to the controller and I won't be storing the callbacks in the DB anyway. So I have two choices - create a `CallbackController` or create a custom route like to:

```
get '/callback' => 'callbacks#index'
```

What would be the right thing to do here?

Comment: Custom routes sounds good. You dont have to change the controller name in order to get a specific url instead you can go for custom routes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) for this:

```
resource :callback, only: [:index]
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because the in the routes dsl a resource is a singular entity part of a collection and only a collection object can have the index action, see the last three comments below [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25724591/1836143).

Comment: Also check the link you provided: "creates six different routes in your application, all mapping to the Geocoders controller:" - the index action is not among them.